# How to have per MACHINE kernel configuration in Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe, yocto-recipe

I have a Yocto recipe for a Linux kernel fork, I need to change the defconfig for the different machines I need to support.
One of the machines uses an in-tree defconfig, the others will need out-of-tree defconfigs (and devicetrees eventually). This is similar to [This unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74120480/how-to-src-uriappend-per-machine).

The problem I'm running into is that with my file structure, bitbake cannot find the defconfig, when I make a machine specific `SRC_URI`.

```
recipe-folder
   |-files
   |   |-machineA
   |   |   |-machineA.patch
   |   |-machineB
   |   |   |-defconfig
   |   |   |-machineB.patch
   |-linux-recipe_0.1.bb
```

If I'm trying to build for machineB, and I do:

```
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
```

Yocto is able to find the defconfig and build, see [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265618/yocto-install-different-config-files-based-on-machine-type-or-target-image).

But, If I want the recipe to support both machineA and B:

```
KBUILD_DEFCONFIG:machineA = "machineA_intree_defconfig"
SRC_URI:machineA += "file://machineA.patch"

SRC_URI:machineB += "file://defconfig file://machineB.patch"
```

And try and build machineB Yocto cannot find the defconfig file.

Even If I add the lines:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend:machineA := "${THISDIR}/files/machineA:"
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend:machineB := "${THISDIR}/files/machineB:"
```

Yocto still cannot find the files.

How do I have `SRC_URI` work on a per-machine basis?

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
SRC_URI:machineA += "file://machineA/machineA.patch"

SRC_URI:machineB += "file://machineB/defconfig \
                     file://machineB/machineB.patch"
```

The filename you specify within the URL can be either an absolute or relative path to a file.

More details can be found here:

https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.0/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-fetching.html#local-file-fetcher-file

https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.0/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html#term-FILESPATH